# Rails Console not showing data present in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on rails with MongoDB using mongoid gem. I have set up MongoDB on OSX using brew.I took the data dump from the server and restored it on local machine. I can view data present in my database using mongo shell. But when I am using rails console to get the data it returns nothing.

Example when I run this command in rails console  I get the result as  [].The same command on the server gives 1 record.

```
Network.all.to_a
```

Whereas in the database there is 1 record which belongs to Network collection.
The database mentioned in the mongoid.yml is the same as that shown in mongo shell.

The network model is described as

```
class Network
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 has_many :network_devices
 field :network_id, type: String
 field :node_mac, type: String
 field :version, type: String
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `network` model?

Comment: I believe `mongoid.yml` is loaded in `production` env only. Try to run: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec irb`.

Comment: @mudasobwa The rails console command be default runs in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the Development database then you need to set the environment for rails to development when accessing the rails console.

There are two ways that I know of to do this, (1) before your command set the environmental variable `RAILS_ENV=development`, or you can export it. (2) The other method is using the `-e` flag followed by the desired environment, so if you were trying to use the development environment rails console, it would be `bundle exec rails c -e development`

I hope that helps.

Comment: When we start rails console without specifying environment by default it starts in development mode.

Comment: That will be dependent on your application configuration, by which I mean RAILS/config/application.rb

Answer (score 0):

So it may seem very weird but restarting my laptop solved the problem.